# Need Clarification in NEGPARENw.d

Tags: sas

The NEGPARENw.d reads the values `-2000 as (20,00)` based on the w.d 
is there anyway to do the same in SAS 9.1?

```
I read a value 00005000- as character value and then converted to numeric value
-5000 
   TEMP=000005000-
 Temp= COMPRESS(TEMP,'-')
 TEMP=-(INPUT(TEMP,16.2)) format  NEGPARENw.d  its not working
 PRoc report;
 .....
 define temp /display format = NEGPAREN16.2
```

Run;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NEGPARENw.d format exists in 9.1.3, so there's no particular reason it wouldn't work the same in 9.1.3 as it would in later versions.